# handlebars - is it possible to access parent context in a partial?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I've got a handlebar template that loads a partial for a sub-element.

I would need to access a variable from the parent context in the calling template, from within the partial. `..` doesn't seem to resolve to anything inside the partial.

Simplified code goes like this:

**the template**

```
    {{#each items}} 
        {{> item-template}}
    {{/each}}
```

**the partial**

```
    value is {{value}}
```

(obviously the real code is more complicated but it's the same principle, within the partial `..` appears to be undefined.)

---

To show it's undefined, I've used a very simple helper `whatis` like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('whatis', function(param) {
    console.log(param);
});
```

and updated the above code to this:

**updated template**

```
    {{#each items}} 
        {{whatis ..}}  <-- Console shows the correct parent context
        {{> item-template}}
    {{/each}}
```

**updated partial**

```
    {{whatis ..}}  <-- Console shows "undefined"
    value is {{value}}
```

Is there a way to go around that issue? Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** There's an open issue relating to this question on [handlebars' github project](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/182)

Answer (score 41):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this question. This functionality exists now in Handlebars.

Do this:

```
{{#each items}} 
    {{! Will pass the current item in items to your partial }}
    {{> item-template this}} 
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks @james-andres. Good to know that's finally in. I'll give it a spin to confirm..

Comment: Just tested this. Doenst work for me unfortunately. The parent context does not get passed. "this" only refers to the items[:index]  so the parent context is left out. And if you pass "..", which would include the parent context, you cant access the current item in the partial.

Comment: You need at least [version 2.0.0 alpha 1](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/handlebars.js/) for this to work. Also check [these comments](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/182#issuecomment-32659931), as it might work a bit different.

Comment: @Hans, you can pass `{{> item-template parent=..}}` and then call `{{parent.stuff}}` in the item-template to access something from outside the each.

Comment: How to access properties of context passed to child by ```this```.

Answer (score 22):

Working fiddle (inspired by handlebars pull request #385 by AndrewHenderson) 
http://jsfiddle.net/QV9em/4/

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('include', function(options) {
    var context = {},
        mergeContext = function(obj) {
            for(var k in obj)context[k]=obj[k];
        };
    mergeContext(this);
    mergeContext(options.hash);
    return options.fn(context);
});
```

Here's how you'd setup the parent template:

```
{{#each items}} 
    {{#include parent=..}}
        {{> item-template}}
    {{/include}}
{{/each}}
```

And the partial:

```
value is {{parent}}
```

Comment: I preferred this approach for its cleanliness and flexibility relative to the others

Comment: in handlebars 2.0, this functionality [will be included](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/182)

Comment: This is great. Keep in mind that if you pass a partial into a partial you'll need to reference the parent like so: `{{parent.parent.id}}`

Answer (score 18):

As of **2.0.0** [**partials now supports passing in values**](https://github.com/dmarcotte/idea-handlebars/issues/96).

```
{{#each items}}
    {{> item-template some_parent_var=../some_parent_var}}
{{/each}}
```

Took me awhile to find this, hope it's useful for someone else too!

Comment: You have a typo: it should be: '{{> item-template some_var=../some_parent_var}}' but thanks for the info, it helped a lot, I've posted a fiddle with several examples using your and @StefanHayden answer, I've up voted both. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7pLxa19/)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to pass the parent context to the partial is to do the loop inside the partial. This way the parent context is passed by default and when you do the loop inside the partial the `{{../variable}}` convention can access the parent context.

[example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/STHayden/uH9YR/).

**The Data**

```
{
  color: "#000"
  items: [
    { title: "title one" },
    { title: "title two" },
  ]
}
```

**The Template**

```
<div class="mainTemplate">
  Parent Color: {{color}}
  {{> partial}}
</div>
```

**The Partial**

```
<div>
  {{#each items}}
    <div style="color:{{../color}}">
      {{title}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use some of the proposed solutions on the comments from the link to github:

https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/182#issuecomment-4206666
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/182#issuecomment-4445747

They create helpers to pass the info to the partial.

Comment: Yeah! Sometimes we miss the obvious looking for other solutions. At least 'til they release a milestone or a new version.

Comment: That's just an incredibly inelegant solution

Comment: Think off a temporary solution if you don't want to browse the source code and fix it yourself. I hate this kind of "workaroud" (even this word seems wrong to me) but it works and can save the day in a tight deadline.

Answer (score 2):

I created an each Helper function that includes the parent key/values within the subcontext under the key parentContext.

http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewHenderson/kQZpu/1/

**Note: Underscore is a dependency.**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachIncludeParent', function ( context, options ) {
var fn = options.fn,
    inverse = options.inverse,
    ret = "",
    _context = [];
    $.each(context, function (index, object) {
        var _object = $.extend({}, object);
        _context.push(_object);
    });
if ( _context && _context.length > 0 ) {
    for ( var i = 0, j = _context.length; i < j; i++ ) {
        _context[i]["parentContext"] = options.hash.parent;
        ret = ret + fn(_context[i]);
    }
} else {
    ret = inverse(this);
}
return ret;
```

});

To be used as follows:

```
{{#eachIncludeParent context parent=this}}
    {{> yourPartial}}
{{/eachIncludeParent}}
```

Access parent context values in your partial using `{{parentContext.value}}`

Comment: How does this fix the problem? also, there's a `var option=` that doesn't seem to be used subsequently..

Comment: If you use this helper, you will have access to one object in the partial template which contains all of the values, both the parent and the child object. It's basically a merged context.

Comment: Note: The child and parent values will be on the same level at that point.

Comment: May help as a workaround, but should be noted it pollutes the original objects passed to the template by adding parent context variables to them.. this might not be ideal for everything.. also `var option = context[i].value || context[i]` should be taken out, it doesn't do anything...

Comment: I concur that this is definitely a workaround while the functionality is missing from Handlebars. _.defaults only adds to the object, as opposed to _.extend which will override matching key values. The object is only being polluted in the local scope of the helper. The helper uses the object to return a string and that's the end of it. I don't think there is a need to be concerned about object pollution in this case.

Comment: The object pollution carries on past the scope of the helper. If you run this through an array of object and log your objects *after* the handlebar code runs, you'll see each object retain the extra properties. Could become a huge problem with models for instance..

Comment: You were right. I was actually working on solving this problem since I last wrote. I've modified the original code above. See what you think.

Answer (score 1):

I needed dynamic form attributes for something like this...

```
    {{#each model.questions}}
      <h3>{{text}}</h3>

          {{#each answers}}
                {{formbuilder ../type id ../id text}}
            {{/each}}

    {{/each}}
```

and a helper like so...

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('formbuilder', function(type, id, qnum, text, options)
    {
        var q_type = options.contexts[0][type],
            a_id = options.contexts[1].id,
            q_number = options.contexts[0][qnum],
            a_text = options.contexts[1].text;


            return new Handlebars.SafeString(
                    '<input type=' + q_type + ' id=' + a_id + ' name=' + q_number + '>' + a_text + '</input><br/>'
            );
    });
```

Which produces...

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="surveyQ0">First question</input>
```

My model is a big blob of arrays and objects mixed together.    What's noteworthy is that using '../' like so '../type', passes in the parent model as the context, and without it, such as with 'id', it passes in the current model as the context.

Answer (score 0):

To get specifically the parent of the partial (where you may be several partials deep) then follow the other answers like SeanWM.

If you know that the parent is the main template then you can use @root which resolves to the top-most context no matter how deep you are.

e.g. {{@root.rootObject.rootProperty}}

It is a pity that ../../.. does not go up past a partial.