# Access properties of the parent with a Handlebars 'each' loop

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Consider the following simplified data:

```
var viewData = {
    itemSize: 20,
    items: [
        'Zimbabwe', 'dog', 'falafel'
    ]
};
```

And a Handlebars template:

```
{{#each items}}
    <div style="font-size:{{itemSize}}px">{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

This won't work because within the `each` loop, the parent scope is not accessible -- at least not in any way that I've tried. I'm hoping that there's a way of doing this though!

Answer (score 498, accepted):

There are two valid ways to achieve this.

#### Dereference the parent scope with `../`

By prepending `../` to the property name, you can reference the parent scope.

```
{{#each items}}
    <div style="font-size:{{../itemSize}}px">{{this}}</div>
    {{#if this.items.someKey}}
       <div style="font-size:{{../../itemSize}}px">{{this}}</div>  
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

You can go up multiple levels via repeating the `../`. For example, to go up two levels use `../../key`.

For more information, see the [Handlebars documentation on paths](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context).

#### Dereference the root scope with `@root`

By prepending `@root` to the property path, you can navigate downwards from the topmost scope (as shown in [caballerog's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36725440/24874)).

For more information, see the [Handlebars documentation on @data variables](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#data-variables).

Comment: Just a note on using ../ to get parent properties. If you have a each statement with a nested #if then just doing ../ only gets you to the level of the #each. So you have to do ../../itemSize to get back to the parent outside of the #each

Comment: How can I get this functionality in mustache.js templating engine ?

Comment: @blushrt you don't. That's handlebars specific

Comment: @TheTaxPayer you just saved me an immense amount of headache!  rock on with your socks on :)

Comment: What about passing an upper level #each value into a helper

Comment: Does this work with all versions of handlebars ? I am trying the same with handlebars.runtime-v1.1.2 and it doesn't work.. !!

Comment: @YugandharPathi, looks like 1.1.2 was released in Nov 2013 which is after this answer was posted, so yes it should work. Maybe open a new question that explains your problem.

Comment: To expand a little, this works with other block helpers like #with. Props to @Theston.EFox for his comment as well.

Comment: This is completely unreadable with large blocks but also appears to be the only solution

Comment: Please see @caballerog's answer below - `@root` ftw! https://stackoverflow.com/a/36725440/422845

Comment: A note that @TheStoneFox's comment no longer applies as of Handlebars 4 - #if no longer introduces an extra level.

Answer (score 74):

The new method is using dot notation, the slash notation is deprecated (http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html).

So, the actual method to access to the parents elements are the following:

```
@root.grandfather.father.element
@root.father.element
```

In your specific example, you would use:

```
{{#each items}}
 <div style="font-size:{{@root.viewData.itemSize}}px">{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Another method from the official documentation(http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) is using alias

> The each helper also supports block parameters, allowing for named
>   references anywhere in the block.
>
> ```
> {{#each array as |value key|}}  
>  {{#each child as |childValue childKey|}}
>      {{key}} - {{childKey}}. {{childValue}}   
>  {{/each}} 
> {{/each}}
> ```
>
> Will create a key and value variable that children may access without
>   the need for depthed variable references. In the example above, {{key}} > is identical to {{@../key}} but in many cases is more readable.

Comment: Going up one level for me worked using "@root.itemSize".

Comment: Technically that's not going up one level - it's going down one level from root, and works only if you are one level down. This approach does not work if you do not know your current nesting level.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you need to use `if` statement inside `each` block. Use built-in `lookup` property for reaching a root object whose key can be given dynamically by an outer `each` loop, for example.

The following works in both an `each` loop and nested `each` loop as well:

```
{{#each anArray}}
   {{#each (lookup ../anObject this)}}
      {{#if (lookup @root name)}}
      `Something to be shown if the value of 'name' here can be found as a key at the root object and, if its value is boolean, its value is 'true'.`
      {{/if}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

`anArray` is an array given at the root object.

`anObject` is an object given at the root object.

`anObject` has a `name` property.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ../ dereferencing does not seem to work through partials. But we can add properties to the context passed into the partial:

```
Name: {{parent.name}}

{{#each children}}
    {{> childpartial this parent=../parent}}
{{/each}}
```

childpartial:

```
{{name}} is child of {{parent.name}}
```

More:
[handlebars - is it possible to access parent context in a partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411538/handlebars-is-it-possible-to-access-parent-context-in-a-partial)

Answer (score 0):

We can access parent using {{../parent.propertyname}}