# Access a variable outside the scope of a Handlebars.js each loop

Tags: javascript, templates, scope, each, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars.js template, just like this:

```
{{externalValue}}

<select name="test">
    {{#each myCollection}}
       <option value="{{id}}">{{title}} {{externalValue}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

And this is the generated output:

```
myExternalValue

<select name="test">
       <option value="1">First element </option>
       <option value="2">Second element </option>
       <option value="3">Third element </option>
</select>
```

As expected, I can access the `id` and `title` fields of every element of `myCollection` to generate my select. And outside the select, my `externalValue` variable is correctly printed ("myExternalValue").

Unfortunately, in options' texts, `externalValue` value is never printed out.

My question is: how can I access a variable outside the scope of the handlebars.js each from within the loop?

Answer (score 547, accepted):

Try

```
<option value="{{id}}">{{title}} {{../externalValue}}</option>
```

The `../` path segment references the parent template scope that should be what you want.

Comment: If future readers are still having trouble like I was, have a look at the comment for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12297980/149998) here. It took me a while after seeing this answer to see that one. You may need to use `../` repeatedly depending on how many scopes away from the value you are.

Comment: Am I crazy or is this type of valuable information nowhere to be found on the handlebars docs???

Comment: @spliter Ugh, yeah, I'm an idiot. I don't know how I didn't see that.  Forest for the trees or something.

Comment: @spliter will this work on ember handlebars.. it seems not to be working

Comment: No idea @kweku360. This works for normal hadlebars. Might be that Ember is using customized version of handlebars where this functionality is implemented with another means

Comment: Thank you man, this works perfectly also with Foundation 6 Panini.

Answer (score 19):

Or you can use absolute path like this:

```
<option value="{{id}}">{{title}} {{@root.user.path.to.externalValue}}</option>
```

Answer (score 9):

I saw many links with 404 for documentation about this topic.

I update it with this one, it is working in *April 1st 2020*:

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#path-expressions

Some helpers like #with and #each allow you to dive into nested objects. When you include ../ segments into your path, Handlebars will change back into the parent context.

```
    {{#each people}}
    {{../prefix}} {{firstname}} 
    {{/each}}
```

Even though the name is printed while in the context of a comment, it can still go back to the main context (the root-object) to retrieve the prefix.

WARNING

The exact value that ../ will resolve to varies based on the helper that is calling the block. Using ../ is only necessary when context changes. Children of helpers such as {{#each}} would require the use of ../ while children of helpers such as {{#if}} do not.

```
{{permalink}}
{{#each comments}}
  {{../permalink}}

  {{#if title}}
    {{../permalink}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

In this example all of the above reference the same prefix value even though they are located within different blocks. This behavior is new as of Handlebars 4, the [release notes](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/release-notes.md) discuss the prior behavior as well as the migration plan.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the original question, but I faced a similar problem -
I have a custom helper that was not rendering the variables inside of it.

My helper was similar to the handlebars `if` helper, so it should not have needed the `../path` syntax.
Turns out I was using a **fat arrow function** when registering the helper, and `this` is different inside a **fat arrow function**.

Changing this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', (v1, v2, options) => {
```

to:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function (v1, v2, options)  {
```

fixed it for me