# Accessing parent object value in #each iterator in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am using `handlebars.runtime-v1.3.0` and I am not sure how to access parent object value in `#each`. Here is my code:

data object:

```
var data = {
    data : {
        question : "work",
        sub : "pref",
        value : [0,1,2]
    }
};
```

Template:

```
{{#each data.data.value}}
    <div class="option" data-value="{{this}}" data-question="{{../question}}" data-subcat="{{../sub}}">
        <img src="/images/image.png" alt="" class="image" />
        <span class="style-name"></span>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

I am not able to get the values at `{{../question}}` and `{{../sub}}`.

> I have been searching for the answer for 1 day and I found these links:
>   [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297959/access-properties-of-the-parent-with-a-handlebars-each-loop), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645084/access-a-variable-outside-the-scope-of-a-handlebars-js-each-loop). None of them is working for me, so please
>   don't mark the question duplicate on the basis of this.

Comment: Are you precompiling your templates, such as with grunt?

Comment: @gfullam yes, I am using gulp for that with gulp-handlebars plugin v2.0.0

Comment: So your runtime and compiler versions appear different. This may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Well, I suppose the gulp plugin version may not correlate. What version of Handlebars do you have [defined in your packages.json](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-handlebars#compiling-using-a-specific-handlebars-version)?

Comment: @gfullam everything is working... I have made full webapp and it is working pretty fine. Just this accessing parent object isn't working.. I have made one more app with same configs and things are working pretty fine over there.. entry in package.json is "gulp-handlebars": "2.0.0"

Comment: @gfullam I have tried to change the version, still not working. currently "gulp-handlebars": "^1.0.0"  in my package.json.

Comment: You should find something like this in packages.json: `"handlebars": "^1.3.0"` What version number is here? If none is specified, [try specifying the same version](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-handlebars#compiling-using-a-specific-handlebars-version) as your runtime compiler. Handlebars has changed the meaning of `../` since v1.3.0, (see [Compatibility notes](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/release-notes.md#v400---september-1st-2015)), so having matching versions for precompilation and runtime is important.

Answer (score 0):

The foreach loop is for `data.data.value` not `data.data`

try

```
{{data.data.question}}
```

or

```
{{data.question}}
```

additionally is you loop working fine? i cant see the rest of your code but i would guess that the foreach should be on data.value rather than data.data.value

Comment: `data.data.question` or `data.question` won't work because currently control is at `data.data.value`. Look is working fine at `data.data.value`, it should be `data.data.value`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `{{../data.data.question}}` and it works fine now :)