# iterating over objects in express-handlebars

Tags: html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

this is the model I pass to my handlebars template

```
module.exports = function(showHeader, userId){ // the data model
  return {
    userId: userId,
    seminars: userSeminars;
  };
};

var userSeminars = [{ // some information
    seminarId: 1,
    isRated: true
}, {
    seminarId: 2,
    isRated: false
}];
```

and when rendering my template I use this HTML code

```
{{#each seminars}}
    <div class="seminarContainer">

        {{#if isRated}}
            <button onclick="loadStatistics({{seminarId}}, {{userId}})">Do Something 1</button>
        {{else}}
            <button onclick="loadQuestionnaire({{seminarId}})">Do Something 2</button>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

but when debugging, `{{userId}}` is undefined. I went for this test routine and write it **above** the each-loop

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   alert({{userId}}); // this works
});
```

`userId` is not undefined. But when iterating over the array it is undefined. How can I leave the array scope within the loop? I would have to access the data model object, not an attribute in the array.

---

**EDIT**

[Access a variable outside the scope of a Handlebars.js each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645084/access-a-variable-outside-the-scope-of-a-handlebars-js-each-loop)

When I want to leave the scope I can use `{{../userId}}`

Within the loop

`<p>{{../userId}}</p>`

works fine but when using this for parameters like

`onclick="loadStatistics({{seminarId}}, {{../userId}})"`

the second parameter is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick search I found this:

[Access a variable outside the scope of a Handlebars.js each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645084/access-a-variable-outside-the-scope-of-a-handlebars-js-each-loop)

I'll sum it up, there's an option given by handlebars to **use the `../` syntax to make a reference to the parent scope**.

So for example:

`<button onclick="loadStatistics({{seminarId}}, {{../userId}})">Do Something 1</button>`

---

EDIT:

With further looking I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297959/access-properties-of-the-parent-with-a-handlebars-each-loop/12297980#12297980) to a similar question. Apparently, because you went another level up in the scope chain when you declared an `#if`, you then need to take that into consideration as well.

```
{{#if isRated}}
    <button onclick="loadStatistics({{seminarId}}, {{../../userId}})">Do Something 1</button>
{{else}}
    <button onclick="loadQuestionnaire({{seminarId}})">Do Something 2</button>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: hm yes, this is a good start but when passing in parameters `onclick="loadStatistics({{seminarId}}, {{../userId}})"` it is still undefined. When writing `<p>{{../userId}}</p>` it works

Comment: I edited my answer, please try it and let me know how it went.