# handlebars parameter not defined in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Here is my route.

```js
router.get("/blocks/:id", (req, res) => {
    res.render("../views/block", {
        data: data,
        blockId: req.params.id,
    });
});
```

Here is my view

```html
<div class="row">
    {{#each data}}
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1>/blocks/{{blockId}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

1. In my view, I loop through the `data`. `data` is completely valid there.  Problem I have is in `<h1>`, `blockId` doesn't print anything. The reason that's causing this is the loop of `#each data`. As soon as I remove the loop, `blockId` is correct after that. What I want is  that `blockId` should be the same for all elements of `data`.
2. How can I grab the parameter from url in `handlebars` file to pass `a href` element? In this case, I would not need to return `blockId` again from express.

Comment: You would need to step up a context level when in the loop. As in `{{../blockId}}` or `{{@root.blockId}}`. See: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#path-expressions

Comment: Thank you . That worked out well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access a variable outside the scope of a Handlebars.js each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645084/access-a-variable-outside-the-scope-of-a-handlebars-js-each-loop)

Answer (score 2):

Some helpers like `#with` and `#each` change the *context* of the data, so you need to include `../` to move up into parent contexts. See https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context

For your example, this looks like

```html
<div class="row">
    {{#each data}}
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1>/blocks/{{../blockId}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

For the 2nd part, handlebars can't read from other window variables (like [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)), so passing this down as `blockId` in your route is the correct way to expose this information.