# How can I access the parameter of a Handlebars inline partial from inside a loop?

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm working on a Handlebars project and trying to use an inline partial. I'm trying to access the `key` parameter from within a loop.

```
{{#*inline "myPartial"}}
  <div class="actionOverlay">
    {{#each (lookup items key) }}
      <span class="{{classes}} key-{{key}}" title="{{title}}"></span>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/inline}}
```

And then invoking this inline partial with `{{> myPartial key="0R"}}`. The variable `items` is an array of objects with `classes` and `title` as keys.

Unfortunately `{{key}}` renders as empty string, no doubt because there is no `key` key in the `items` objects. I've also tried `{{@root.key}}` and that doesn't work.

How can I access the partial's parameter from within the loop?

Please note that I'm not trying to use a partial from within a loop, but trying to use a loop in a partial and to access the partial's parameter from within the loop.

Comment: You need to step-up a context level. You can use `key-{{../key}}`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access a variable outside the scope of a Handlebars.js each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645084/access-a-variable-outside-the-scope-of-a-handlebars-js-each-loop)

Comment: Thanks, guys! `{{../key}}` did work. I don't know why that worked but `{{@root.key}}` didn't.

Comment: `{{@root.key}}` would work only if `key` was a property of the (root) object you passed to your template function. As `key` is a parameter to the inline partial, it is available within the context in which the partial is executed, but this is not the same as `@root`.