# How to sent an id outside the loop of handlebars to the form inside the handlebars?

Tags: node.js, loops, handlebars.js

```
   <form method="POST"  action="/admin/update-blog/{{blogs._id}}"> 
  <div class="form-group">
  
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">HEADING</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="{{blogs.heading}}" name="heading">
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">BLOG</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" value="{{blogs.blog}}" name="blog">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<br><br>
<h2><i><b>Comments</b></i></h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Message</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each blogs.comments}}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
 
            <td>
       <form method="POST" action="/admin/delete-comment">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="myInput"readonly aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" value="{{this.email}}" name="email">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">delete</button>
</form>

      </td>
      <td>{{this.message}}</td>
 
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can i pass the {{blogs._id}} to a form which is inside a loop called   {{#each blogs.comments}} .Is that possible.I am trying to delete a comment based on the email and the id of blog.Here the blog id is there in the top of code which is the first form where it displays the blog .And in the second form it displays the comments for the blog.
For me it is not possible to pass the id from blog to second loop(display comment).
I want to pass the id of blog to the action of the form in  second loop(display comment)

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access a variable outside the scope of a Handlebars.js each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645084/access-a-variable-outside-the-scope-of-a-handlebars-js-each-loop)

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="{{id}}">{{title}} {{../externalValue}}</option>

//The ../ path segment references the parent template scope that should be what you want.
```