# Interpolate variable inside "each" loop in Handlebars

Tags: html, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am rendering this in an express app which uses handlebars as template engine:

```
 res.render("movies", { data: pages, arraypages:arrayPages, movie:movie})
```

"arrayPages" is an array:
[
1, 2, 3, 4,
5, 6, 7
]

"movie" is a string like "top gun"

Inside the handlebars template there is:

```
{{#each arraypages}}
<form action="/getmoviepage" method="post">
    <a>{{this}}</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="{{movie}}" value="{{this}}">
</form>
{{/each}}
```

Which outputs:

```
<form action="/getmoviepage" method="post">
    <a>1</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="1">
</form>

<form action="/getmoviepage" method="post">
    <a>2</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="2">
</form>

<form action="/getmoviepage" method="post">
    <a>3</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="3">
</form>

<form action="/getmoviepage" method="post">
    <a>4</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="4">
</form>

<form action="/getmoviepage" method="post">
    <a>5</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="5">
</form>

<form action="/getmoviepage" method="post">
    <a>6</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="6">
</form>

<form action="/getmoviepage" method="post">
    <a>7</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="7">
</form>
```

As you can see the "movie" variable is not rendered (the variable should render inside the "name" attribute). If I put the variable outside the "each" loop is rendered OK.

```
{{movie}}  //This is rendered OK, outside the "each" loop
{{#each arraypages}}
<form action="/getmoviepage" method="post">
    <a>{{this}}</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="{{movie}}" value="{{this}}">
</form>
{{/each}}
```

How do I render a variable inside a "each" loop in handlebars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{../movie}}" value="{{this}}">
```

The `../` path segment references the parent template scope that should be what you want.

[Potential Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645084/access-a-variable-outside-the-scope-of-a-handlebars-js-each-loop)