# Reaching an object in the general context using "each" function of handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm trying to use handlebars. It worked pefectly until I used the each function. The function works fine but it seems like it references everything to the parameters it takes. Therefore I cannot reach the object I want. I think a bit of code will be clearer anyway.

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="handlebar">
    {{#each items}}
    <p>{{this.name}} {{this.surname}}</p>
    <p>{{somethingInTheGeneralContext}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var source   = $("#handlebar").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var context = {
            items: [
                {
                    name:"Paul",
                    surname:"Buchon"
                },
                {
                    name:"Pierre",
                    surname:"Bino"
                },
                {
                    name:"Jean",
                    surname:"Duflou"
                }
            ],   
            somethingInTheGeneralContext: "It works !"
        };
        var html = template(context);
        $("#myDiv").html(html);
    });
</script>
```

This prints :

Paul Buchon

Pierre Bino

Jean Duflou

And my somethingInTheGeneralContext is lost somewhere... 
Any idea how I can fix it ? 
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297959/access-properties-of-the-parent-with-a-handlebars-each-loop

Comment: Sorry I did not find it on the website and gooogling it. Thks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use `{{../param}}` to break out of the each context and go back to the parent level, where `somethingInTheGeneralContext` exists:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="handlebar">
    {{#each items}}
    <p>{{this.name}} {{this.surname}}</p>
    <p>{{../somethingInTheGeneralContext}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```