# Can't get the right value in #each and #each

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

there are some data：

```
var data = [
  {id:"a",b:[{name:"1",value:"a"},{name:"2",value:"x"}],c:"a"}
  {id:"b",b:[{name:"2",value:"b"},{name:"3",value:"c"}],c:"b"}
]
```

and in the Template

```
...
{{#each data}}
 {{id}}
   select>
  {{#each b}}
       option   {{#if equal value c}} selected   {{/if}}   >
           name
       option>
  {{/each}}
  
{{/each}}
..
```

The function:

```
 Template.temp.equal = function(value,test){
     console.log(value);
     console.log(test);
  }
```

and the "test" is undefined,In other words,In the second #each  can't read the value of the First #each  .
What's the step I have forgotten? how can I  get the  value of property "c" in second #each ?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297959/access-properties-of-the-parent-with-a-handlebars-each-loop

Comment: @go-oleg Thanks for your remind .It can work well

Answer (score 0):

U can do it with registerHelper;

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("equal",function(value,test,options) {
    if(value==c)
       return options.fn(this);
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

And your template

```
{{#equal value c}}
   selected
{{/equal}}
```