# Handlebars expression outside of #each helper

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

How can I add a dynamic class name in an `#each` block to my Handlebars template, where the class name isn't part of the block scope?

```
<div class="{{className}}>...</div>

{{#each items}}
    <div class="{{className}}">
        ...
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

The first `<div>` will see the class name, whereas the second one in the `#each` block doesn't, because it is now looking for a `className` in `items`.
Is it possible to see outside of the `items` scope in the `#each` block?

Comment: You can edit the question appropriately.

Comment: Try to follow this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297959/access-properties-of-the-parent-with-a-handlebars-each-loop/12297980#12297980

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back one scope (or possibly more), using `../` to access a global variable. In your case if your pass i `className` as one attribute and ìtems`as another, your code should look like this:

```
{{#each items}}
   <div class="{{../className}}">
    ...
   </div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@root.classname` will help on any depth of scope.