# How to use if inside a if condition in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, express-handlebars

```
{{#if docs}}
    {{#each docs}}
        <h4>customer number : {{this.customer}}</h4>
        <h4>number of liters required : {{this.volume}}</h4>
        {{#if alldri}}
            {{#each alldri}}
                <h5>{{this.name}}</h5>
            {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

both docs and alldri are the JSON arrays.All the objects under docs array are printing well but the not able to see objects under alldri array.

alldri array is

```
[ { _id: 5c94c61f955fa804fc96657c,
    name: '1',
    phonenumber: '9640121413',
    email: 'taditarun123@gmail.com'
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5c94c683955fa804fc96657d,
    name: '2',
    phonenumber: '9493447471',
    email: 't@gmail.com'
    __v: 0 } ]
```

docs array is

```
[ { _id: 5c93a9812671d127785c105e,
customer: '1',
merchant: '11',
volume: '12',
__v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: it would help if you add a sample of your data

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually not with the `if` directives. It's with scope. You lose access to the parent scope when you're inside an `each` directive. So you are not able to access `alldri` inside. That's why it's evaluating to false and not rendering that content.

See [Access properties of the parent with a Handlebars 'each' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297959/access-properties-of-the-parent-with-a-handlebars-each-loop).

Your code will work if your template is changed to:

```
{{#if docs}}
    {{#each docs}}
        <h4>customer number : {{this.customer}}</h4>
        <h4>number of liters required : {{this.volume}}</h4>
        {{#if ../alldri}}
            {{#each ../alldri}}
                <h5>{{this.name}}</h5>
            {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Note the `../alldri`.

https://jsfiddle.net/nowgy52m/7/