# Using array to replace hardcodded if else

Tags: handlebars.js, jsreport

<kbd>[working playground](https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/3bMVlW3P)</kbd>

The following code is my current working code:

```
{{#each ../cellHeaders}} 
    {{#if_eq this 'Date'}}
    <c t="d" s="4">
        <v>{{lookup ../this this}}</v>
    </c>
    {{else}}
        {{#if_eq this 'birthday'}}
        <c t="d" s="4">
          <v>{{lookup ../this this}}</v>
        </c>
        {{else}}
        <c t="inlineStr" s="2">
        <is>
          <t>{{lookup ../this this}}</t>
        </is>
        </c>
        {{/if_eq}} 
    {{/if_eq}} 
{{/each}}
```

I would like to replace the manual string inputted on if else by using something like:

```
{{#each ../cellHeaders}} 
    {{#each ../fielddate}} 
    {{#if_eq ../../this this}}
    <c t="d" s="4">
        <v>{{lookup ../../this ../this}}</v>
    </c>
    {{else}}
    <c t="inlineStr" s="2">
      <is>
        <t>{{lookup ../../this ../this}}</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    {{/if_eq}} 
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

But it's not working. 
jsreport part on italic:
*I've declared the fielddate: `var fielddate= ['date', 'birthday']`;
and registered it: `req.data.fielddate = fielddate;`*

What I expect was using an array to replace the process on my current working code: e.g: `{{#if_eq this 'Date'}}` or `{{#if_eq this 'est_delivery'}}` which is violating DRY rule.

I've tried dereferencing the parent as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12297980/11328122) suggested but apparently it's not working since my jsreport wasn't generating anything.

Any idea?

Example <kbd>[working playground](https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/3bMVlW3P)</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this:

- register the fielddate in script as you were already trying `var fielddate= ['date', 'birthday'];` `req.data.fielddate = fielddate;`
- change your each part to this

--

```
{{#each ../cellHeaders}} 
    {{#ifFieldDate this @root.fielddate}}
        <c t="d" s="4">
            <v>{{lookup ../this this}}</v>
        </c>
    {{else}}
        <c t="inlineStr" s="2">
            <is>
                <t>{{lookup ../this this}}</t>
            </is>
        </c>
    {{/ifFieldDate}}
{{/each}}
```

--

- the helper `ifFieldDate` should be defined like this

--

```
function ifFieldDate (value, fieldNames, opts) {
  const fields = fieldNames.map((f) => f.toLowerCase())

  if (fields.includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
      return opts.fn(this);
  } else {
    return opts.inverse(this);
  } 
}
```

--

live example [here](https://playground.jsreport.net/w/bjrmatos/WvZsoOXk)