# Handlebars.js: How to access parent index in nested each?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

How to access parent @index value in each-loop?

Tried the following:

```
{{#each company}}
{{#each employee}}
  {{../@index}} // how to access company index here?
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

This results to an error:

> Expecting 'ID', got 'DATA'

Answer (score 101, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the example. The correct syntax is `{{@../index}}`.

We are looking at ways that we can support custom naming of these parameters in future versions of the language so this is easier to deal with.
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/907

Comment: The answer marked correct is helpful nonetheless, but this is the correct answer to the question.

Comment: oh looks like this was the first actual answer, my bad

Comment: This does not work in ember v2.2.0. @Andrew Toy has the correct answer.

Answer (score 28):

This worked for me:

```
{{#each company}}
{{setIndex @index}}
{{#each employee}}
  {{../index}}
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

JS:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('setIndex', function(value){
    this.index = Number(value + 1); //I needed human readable index, not zero based
});
```

Just make sure the `company` object doesn't have `index` property.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work if the inner loop is rendered from a template: ``{{>my-template}}`` yields ``Cannot read property 'index' of undefined``. Do you know a solution for that?

Comment: @Lincoln you can try the suggestions here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18026063/271442 - I went for the include helper approach.

Comment: This is an awesome trick. I will share a jsfiddle link. Thanks!

Comment: Here is an extensible version that allows you to set a hash of key/value pairs: http://jsfiddle.net/gfullam/Dc35g/ Example using subexpression: `{{set index=@index indexPlus1=(math @index "+" 1)}}`

Answer (score 16):

**Answer:** `{{@../index}}`

From the [Handlebars docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) (see bottom of 'each' helper section):

*"Nested `each` blocks may access the interation variables via depted paths. To access the parent index, for example, `{{@../index}}` can be used."*

NOTE: I'm using v1.3 so it's at least that old.

REMINDER: Helpers are your last best option. 9/10 there is a better solution.

Comment: this is the actual answer

Comment: {{@key}} is it also supported in older version ?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there's a new syntax in Ember v2.2.0.  I tried all the answers here and they didn't work for me.

What I found worked was naming the parent loop's index and the child loop's index.

```
{{#each parents as |parent parentIndex|}}
    {{parentIndex}}
    {{#each children as |child childIndex|}}
        {{parentIndex}}
        {{childIndex}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

registe an Helper method:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachWithIndex', function(cursor, options) {
    var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse;
    var ret = "";
    var idx = -1;
    //console.log(cursor);
    cursor.forEach(function(item){
        idx++;
        console.log(item.index);
        item.index = idx;
        ret+=fn(item);
    });
    return ret;
});
```

handlebars template:

```
{{#eachWithIndex outer}}
  {{#each inner}}
   {{../index}} // access outer index like this. I used hanlebars V1.3.0
   {{index}} // access inner index
  {{/each}}
{{/eachWithIndex}}
```