# Handlebars.js - Accessing parent index from 2D array

Tags: arrays, indexing, this, each, handlebars.js

I have a 2D array in a JSON object (called table ;)

```
data = {

tableID : "testTable",

table : [
[{type:'a', value:'x'},{type:'a', value:'y'},{type:'a', value:'z'}],
[{type:'a', value:'x'},{type:'a', value:'y'},{type:'a', value:'z'}],
[{type:'a', value:'x'},{type:'a', value:'y'},{type:'a', value:'z'}]
]

};
```

And have been successfully rendering it out with handlebars using the template:

```
<table id = "{{tableID}}-table">

{{#each table}}

    <tr id = "{{../tableID}}-row-{{@index}}">

        {{#each this}}

            <td id = "{{../../tableID}}-row-{{../index}}-col-{{@index}}">

                {{this.type}}-{{this.value}}

            </td>

        {{/each}}

    </tr>

{{/each}}

</table>
```

However, in the td tag id I can't seem to access the parent index
{{../index}} - the index of the row. Nothing is returned:

```
<td id = "testTable-row--col-x">
```

However, I can access the index of the current context {{@index}}.

Any ideas??

Many many thanks in advance!!

Rich

p.s. Using 1.0.0-rc.3

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. It's the direction I've adopted at the moment, but was hoping for something a bit cleaner ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handlebars.js: How to access parent index in nested each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854491/handlebars-js-how-to-access-parent-index-in-nested-each)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open issue/feature on handlebar. You can check the progress for the same [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/491)

However you can check the workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854491/handlebars-js-how-to-access-parent-index-in-nested-each/15505943#15505943)

Answer (score 3):

Since Handlebars version 2.0.0, you can use

```
{{@../index}}
```