# Access parent data in nested array rendering with handlebars

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I have the following data structure:

```
A : 
{
  "B": [
    {
      "C":["Hello", "World"]
    }
  ]
```

}

**A** has an attribute **B** which is an array. Every element of **B** has an attribute **C** which is again an array.

```
<template name="render">
{{#each B}}
{{#each C}}
<div class="clickme">{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
</template>
```

So now I have the event handler where I want to access the element of **B** in which 'this' (== element of **C**) was rendered in. But it seems impossible. How do I do it?

```
Template.render.events({
    "click .clickme" : function (event, template) {
         //template.data == A
         //Template.parentData(0) == A
         //Template.parentData(1) == A
         console.log("what was my parent B?");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go multiple levels upwards by using `../`
In your case, suppose you want index of parent element, then:

`{{@../index}}`

To access another key of your parent element (not applicable in your case): 
`{{../key}}` 
References:

[Access properties of the parent with a Handlebars 'each' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297959/access-properties-of-the-parent-with-a-handlebars-each-loop)

[Handlebars.js: How to access parent index in nested each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854491/handlebars-js-how-to-access-parent-index-in-nested-each)

Edit: To access the parent element from  "click .clickme" event handler, I do not know of a direct way to access from event handler, but one possible way is to create a onclick event in html, and call a function, to which you can pass the parent element (or its index) as parameter. In the function, set is as a session variable, which can then be reffered to in the "click .clickme" event handler.

Template:

```
 <template name="render">
    {{#each B}}
    {{#each C}}
    <div class="clickme" onclick="onclickfunction('{{@../index}}')">{{this}}</div>
    {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
    </template>
```

In client side javascript, define a function:

```
onclickfunction = function(parentindex) {
Session.set('indexofparent',parentindex);
}
```

In "click .clickme" event handler, get the session variable:

```
Template.render.events({
    "click .clickme" : function (event, template) {
         //template.data == A
         //Template.parentData(0) == A
         //Template.parentData(1) == A
         var parentelement = Session.get('indexofparent');
         console.log(parentelement);//Shows index of B.
    }
})
```

P.S. Index of B is a string, use pareseInt(parentelement) to parse to integer.

Comment: thank you but I think I wasn't clear enough: I want to access the parent in the "click .clickme" event handler

Comment: I have edited the answer, please tell me if it works, also if there is slight syntax error here or there, fix it and do let me know so I can correct the same.

Comment: I did not try your new answer, because it is even hackier than what I did. You rely on that the event handler gets executed after the 'onClick' function. What I did was just setting the `data-index` of the div to the `@../index` and getting the index by `$(event.currentTarget).data('index')`. If you put this in your answer I will accept it.