# handlebars partials parameter passing

Tags: parameters, handlebars.js, partials

I am struggling with passing parameters to handlebars partial. I saw the threads [Passing variables through handlebars partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523331/passing-variables-through-handlebars-partial) and [handlebars - is it possible to access parent context in a partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411538/handlebars-is-it-possible-to-access-parent-context-in-a-partial) but still am not able to make it work.

Relevant postion of html (in haml) where I am invoking a partial (the partial is called transactions) is shown below:

```
{{#each totalsByDate}}
{{> transactions this}}
{{/each}}
```

And within the partial, I am trying to print the context but always get "undefined" context.

```
{{showParams this}}
```

Here showParams is just a helper method to log the passed parameter:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('showParams', function(params) {
    console.log("HANDLEBARS params: ", params);
});
```

I thought passing the "this" parameter when invoking the partial should do the trick but it does not seem to work.

Thoughts?

Comment: Seems to work as expected http://jsfiddle.net/vEAhh/

Comment: yes - it does seem to work in that scenario. I am using dynamically loaded templates from files and probably missing something - thanks for setting up the jsfiddle!