# handlebars.js: relative paths in partials not working

Tags: handlebars.js

I replaced some repeating code in my file with a partials, but now the call of an relative part is not working anymore.

I have this data-structure:

```
var data = { staff: [
         {"name": "Alan"},
         {"name": "Bettina"}
         ],"company": "Rad, Inc."};
```

The original template looks like this:

```
<script id="first_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 {{#each staff}}
     <li>Name: {{name}} , Company: {{../company}}</li>
 {{/each}}
 </script>
```

I changed it like this to use a partial:

```
<script id="list-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <li>Name: {{name}} , Company: {{../company}}</li>
</script>

<script id="second_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 {{#each staff}}
    {{> list}}
 {{/each}}
</script>
```

In the example with the partial the company name does not get rendered. I put a working example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/staeff/qwms6h2b/

Does anyone see, why it is not working, what I am trying to do?

Comment: Because partials has its own context, which you passed in. Construction `{{> list}}` is equivalent to `{{> list this}}`.

Comment: Hi raidendev, thanks for answering. I have read up on the context, but am still confused. Wouldn't be `this` the right context, for what I want to do?

Comment: The problem is in `{{../company}}` construction, because you have no upper `../` level in the partial. One of the ways to solve this is to move `#each` inside the partial and name it something like "staffList".  But the right way is to refactor your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by raidendev in the comments

> The problem is in {{../company}} construction, because you have no upper ../ level in the partial. One of the ways to solve this is to move #each inside the partial and name it something like "staffList". But the right way is to refactor your data structure. –  raidendev

Ok, I found out, that my question has been discussed and solved on stackoverflow, but I didn't know, what to search for. See question [handlebars - is it possible to access parent context in a partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9411538/897783) for solutions to my exact problem.