# access parent sub array key handlbars

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have the following array / sub array structure

```
"filters": {
    "types": {
        "34": "Ford",
        "22": "Jeep",
        "18": "Porsche",
    },
    "locations": [
        "Earth",
        "Mars",
        "Moon",
    ]
}
```

and the following handlebars template

```
{{#if filters}}
    {{#each filters}}
        <div class="cars">
            <ul class="cars__list">
                <li class="cars-{{@key}}__title">Filter by {{@key}}:</li>
                <li class="cars-{{@key}}__filters">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="cars-{{@key}}">View All</li>
                    {{#each this}}
                        <li class="cars-{{*want to access filters[key]*}} color={{@key}}">{{this}}</li>
                    {{/each}}
                   </li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

I'm having trouble accessing the filters[types] and filters[locations] within the each this loop.

In my CSS I'm using a classes called `.cars-type` and `.cars-location`. I want to be able to style each list separately and unfortunately target each li with a class. I want to apply these styles within the each this loop.

I can do it within the filters loop by using `{{@key}}` but not in the each this loop

I've tried

```
<li class="cars-{{../filters}}">{{this}}</li>
```

but this just returns the car type like ford - I want the key ie. '34' in this case

```
<li class="cars-{{lookup ../filters @index}}">{{this}}</li>
```

using handlebars helper [lookup](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) but again no luck

```
<li class="cars-{{../this}}">{{this}}</li>
```

and the above which gives me `[object Object]`

I've checked out [handlebars - is it possible to access parent context in a partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411538/handlebars-is-it-possible-to-access-parent-context-in-a-partial), [handlebars.js: relative paths in partials not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808922/handlebars-js-relative-paths-in-partials-not-working) and [Lookup helper in handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433381/lookup-helper-in-handlebars) but no luck with any of the solutions

**EDIT** Here's the HTML output that I want to produce

```
<div class="cars">
    <ul class="cars__list">
        <li class="cars-types__title">Filter by types:</li>
        <li class="cars-types__filters">
          <ul>
            <li class="cars-types">View All</li>
            <li class="cars-types color-34">Ford</li>
            <li class="cars-types color-22">Jeep</li>
            <li class="cars-types color-18">Porsche</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="cars__list">
       <li class="cars-locations__title">Filter by locations:</li>
       <li class="cars-locations__filters">
          <ul>
            <li class="cars-locations">View All</li>
            <li class="cars-locations color-0">Earth</li>
            <li class="cars-locations color-1">Mars</li>
            <li class="cars-locations color-2">Moon</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Should `filters` be an array of objects?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here. `filters["types"]` is an object; it doesn't make sense to build a class name with it. I think you should provide your desired HTML result. Then someone here will be happy to help you.

Comment: @76484 I have added my expect HTML output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reconsider your HTML because a `ul` cannot be a direct child of another `ul`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul#Usage_context

With that said, we can solve your problem. The [Handlebars docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration) have our answer:

> Nested each blocks may access the interation variables via depth based
>   paths. To access the parent index, for example, {{@../index}} can be
>   used.

Therefore, your problematic line should look like the following:

```
<li class="cars-{{@../key}} color-{{@key}}">{{this}}</li>
```